# I want to Avoid duplicated Insert data from vb.net to Access Database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I want to avoid Duplicat what the correct syntax to make this ?

```
Dim StrInsert As String = "Insert Into Job (Name) Select @OtherInfo30 
                           WHERE @OtherInfo30 not in (select name from job)"
```

but from where query wrong

Comment: `where not exists (select 1 from job where name=@otherinfo30)`

Comment: Dim StrInsert As String = "Insert Into Job (Name) Select @OtherInfo30 
                                          where not exists (select 1 from job where name=@otherinfo30) "

                Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(StrInsert, CON)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", row.Cells("otherinfo30").Value)

give me syntax error

Comment: error message
syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '@OtherInfo30 
                                          where @OtherInfo30 not exists (select 1 from job where name=@otherinfo30)'.

Comment: You are defining your param as a different name

Comment: i get same error
do you know another syntax for where and not exits

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar This is Access. Parameters won't work that way.

Comment: You could always define a unique index/constraint on the name field, then handle the exception.  Or slight rework of the other solutions is to preform the query to see if it exists 1st, then based on the result of that preform the insert or not

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that Access SQL supports a where clause on insert, and worse it for sure does not support a sub-query.

Now in a "lot" of cases, if the row does exist, then we often want to update that row, and I can post the code for that.

However, in this case? We test for the row exist, and if not, then run a insert command.

Yes, this does mean two SQL statements, but we DO GET to re-use the parameter!!
(so this is not too much code, and not "too" bad.

So this:

```
    Dim strAddHotel As String = "Zoo5"

    Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand("SELECT ID FROM tblHotels WHERE HotelName = @Hotel",
                    New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.TESTAce))

        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Hotel", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = strAddHotel
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        If cmdSQL.ExecuteScalar = 0 Then
            cmdSQL.CommandText = "INSERT into tblHotels (HotelName) VALUES(@Hotel)"
            cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If

    End Using
```